# Why Azure SignalR Service doesn’t provide Diagnostic or Logs?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-signalr

Azure Monitor diagnostic logs are logs emitted by Azure services that describe the operation of those services or resources. All diagnostic logs available through Azure Monitor share a common top-level schema, with flexibility for each service to emit unique properties for their own events.

But Azure SignalR Service doesn't provide `Diagnostic` or `Logs`. This service has two items under `Monitoring` and these are `Alerts` & `Metrics`. It's shown below -

[image]

`Diagnostic settings` and `Logs` are missing in Azure SignalR Service. Is there any specific reason? It can be `As designed` by Microsoft, `Diagnostic` or `Logs` may not be required but why? There are several Azure services with logs like `Cognitive Services`, `Recovery Services`, `Analysis Services` etc. A typical Azure Service with `Diagnostic settings` or `Logs` looks like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Diagnostics Settings in SignalR is available in azure portal.

[image]